# How to pass parameters using GKStateMachine's states

Tags: ios, swift, state-machine

While entering into state I want to pass parameters with state as follows:

playerStateMachine.enter(pauseState.self, ["score":123, "rank":1])

so I can get that value as follows in didEnter method:

```swift
class pauseState: GKState {
    var userinfo:[String:Any]?

    init(player: SSGameDelegate) {
        super.init(player: player)
    }

    override func didEnter(from previousState: GKState?) {
        super.didEnter(from: previousState)
       //Access input value here
       print(userinfo["score"])
       print(userinfo["rank"])

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don’t pass parameter this way. In you current state,there is a function.

```
func willExit(to nextState: GKState)
```

You can pass parameters over there as `nextState.userinfo[score] = 111`

Comment: Thank  @E.Coms. How can I set the initial value e.g. ["weapon": "sword"] to the current state so I can pass it to the next state?

Comment: Getting error as : Value of type 'GKState' has no member 'userinfo'

Comment: You need to use switch to determine the type of nextState. Or here (nextState as! PauseState).userinfo[“score”]

Comment: When you initiate current state, you put weapon in the init

Answer (score 0):

If you keep track of the state Machine states, you are able to set a parameter before entering the state.  I am not totally sure this is thread safe, I will update as I test further will usage.

```
let alienWaitState = AlienWaitState(game: self)
let alienFlyingState = AlienFlyingState(game: self)

aliensStateMachine = GKStateMachine(states: [
  alienWaitState,
  alienFlyingState,
  AlienAnimateOffState(game: self),
  AlienDeadRemovalState(game: self)
])
```

in this case alienState parameter "associatedAlienName" can be set before entry to the state

```
alienWaitState.associatedAlienName = newAlien.name
aliensStateMachine.enter(AlienWaitState.self)
```

AlienState class, alienWaitState is a subclass

```
class AlienState: GKState {  
    weak var game:GameScene?
    var associatedAlienName:String?  
    ....
```